# Python dictionaries: How to take the value from a the list in the dict

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I use `data["WLGT_at_SBBM"]`, but can't access the `String`.
How can I access `WLGT_at_SBBM`'s value?

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data = {'time':56,'value':'True','order':{'dicts':[{'YXGT_at_ZJFX': '1', 'WLGT_at_SBBM': '16M00000071166792'}]}}
print(data['WLGT_at_SBBM'])
```

Comment: data['order']['dicts'][0]['WLGT_at_SBBM']

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: `print(data['order']['dicts'][0]['WLGT_at_SBBM'])` Just access to smaller part of the dict, one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

A bit confusing but I think

```
print(data['order']['dicts'][0]['WLGT_at_SBBM'])
```

is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'time':56,'value':'True','order':{'dicts':[{'YXGT_at_ZJFX': '1', 'WLGT_at_SBBM': '16M00000071166792'}]}}
print(data['order']['dicts'][0]['WLGT_at_SBBM'])

#16M00000071166792
```

This is a way